# Number of nonnegative solutions of linear Diophantine inequality

Tags: number-theory

Given inequality $Ax + By \le C$, where $A, B, C$ are integers, $A$ and $B$ are coprime and $C < AB$. I need to find number of non-negative integer solutions of it.

Is there exists algorithm which run in polynomial time? For example if $A \le 10^{10}, B \le 10^{10}$ it should work less than a second. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Googling for "counting solutions to linear inequality" gives lots of hits that look relevant: did you look at them? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Of course I tried to google it. But I couldn't find any algorithm which is not obvious bruteforce.

Comment: You are saying "polynomial time" - do you mean $O((number of solutions)^k)$ for some constant k? The obvious brute-force algorithm is polynomial-time in this sense

Comment: I meant polynomial in common sense: $O(\max(len(A), len(B))^k)$

Comment: I think you need to reformulate your requirements to the algorithm complexity. For example, please look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time

Comment: And one more reference about time complexity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_time#Strongly_and_weakly_polynomial_time

Answer (score 1):

I've found a [paper](http://www.iaeng.org/IJAM/issues_v40/issue_1/IJAM_40_1_01.pdf) for you (however it's about more general case).

Welcome to the site!

Comment: I read it before and as far as I understood it contains only very slow algorithm.

Comment: Then include your analysis of the paper into your question. You need to show your own effort on this site, otherwise your question might be put on hold etc.